# How to put buttons, sliders, ect. in the N panel with an addon

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, operator

My goal is to make an addon that makes a new tab in the sidebar with sliders and buttons and stuff that do nothing (it’s my first addon, so I’m just experimenting).

I stole some code from [the cursor array addon tutorial found on the Blender documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/scripting/addon_tutorial.html) just to get the first button made (which I could only figure out how to put in the `VIEW3D_PT_view3d_properties` part of the side panel). [Here is my code thus far](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1QJBNKXEwypAQMqhyVqCgekhrQaDbbva9?usp=sharing).

I’m pretty sure I could figure out how to make all the buttons if I could figure out how to register and unregister multiple classes (as you can see, `class pan` is unregistered).

<sub>I am a beginner with Python so try to answer in simplest terms.</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a very trivial very small very complete add-on. It draws one button in one panel that shows up as the "TLA" tab in the 3D Viewport when the Viewport is in Object Mode.  It only has two classes, but it uses a common technique to register multiple classes by putting their names in an array and processing the array.

For each button you want, add an operator Class with a different name and a new `col.operator`.

```py
# Very small add on to start from

bl_info = {
    "name" : "draw colors",
    "description" : "A skeleton addon",
    "author" : "Marty",
    "version" : (0, 0, 1),
    "blender" : (2, 80, 0),
    "location" : "View3D",
    "warning" : "",
    "support" : "COMMUNITY",
    "doc_url" : "",
    "category" : "3D View"
}

import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.types import Panel

class TLA_OT_operator(Operator):
    """ tooltip goes here """
    bl_idname = "demo.operator"
    bl_label = "I'm a Skeleton Operator"
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.mode == "OBJECT"

    def execute(self, context):

        self.report({'INFO'},
            f"execute()")

        return {'FINISHED'}


class TLA_PT_sidebar(Panel):
    """Display test button"""
    bl_label = "TLA"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "TLA"

    def draw(self, context):
        col = self.layout.column(align=True)
        prop = col.operator(TLA_OT_operator.bl_idname, text="Say Something")

 
classes = [
    TLA_OT_operator,
    TLA_PT_sidebar,
]

def register():
    for c in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(c)


def unregister():
    for c in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(c)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```

Comment: ok so i got the button part but what about adding properties like bool or float?

Comment: I suggest the tutorial series "Scripting for Artists".  You can find most of it on YouTube and it has examples of these things.

Answer (score 1):

Here I have extended [Marty's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/252084/42221) with `bool` and `float` properties:

```py
import bpy

bl_info = {
    "name" : "whatever",
    "description" : "addon",
    "author" : "Marty",
    "version" : (0, 0, 1),
    "blender" : (2, 80, 0),
    "location" : "View3D",
    "warning" : "",
    "support" : "COMMUNITY",
    "doc_url" : "",
    "category" : "3D View"
}

import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.types import Panel

class TLA_OT_operator(Operator):
    """ tooltip goes here """
    bl_idname = "demo.operator"
    bl_label = "I'm a Skeleton Operator"
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.mode == "OBJECT"

    def execute(self, context):

        self.report({'INFO'},
            f"execute()")

        return {'FINISHED'}


class TLA_PT_sidebar(Panel):
    """Display test button"""
    bl_label = "TLA"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "TLA"

    def draw(self, context):
        col = self.layout.column(align=True)
        prop = col.operator(TLA_OT_operator.bl_idname, text="Say Something")
        
        col.prop(context.scene, "my_tool")
        col.prop(context.scene, "my_float")

 
classes = [
    TLA_OT_operator,
    TLA_PT_sidebar,
]

def register():
    
    for c in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(c)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = bpy.props.BoolProperty(
        name='Bool',
        default=False
    )
    bpy.types.Scene.my_float = bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        name='Float',
        default=0.0 
    )
        
def unregister():
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_float
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_bool
    for c in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(c)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```

result:

[image: The new TLA side panel open in the N Panel]

Comment: You do realize you owe me all of the reputation you earn from this answer.  ;)  I'll settle for you doing me the favor of adding a comment to your answer reinforcing my point that this is a 'tip of the iceberg' addition and the OP should follow the "Scripting for Artists" Tutorial to find out the bits they're missing.  Also, I edited your answer so that the code would be consistent with what I would have done and I removed the property group, which you didn't actually use, to make the code clearer.  (Always better for additions to match original style.)  Hope you don't mind.